# Dynamically create dataframes in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Below is the code where i am reading two files and trying to create separate dataframes for both them.I am trying to achieve this dynamically so that I can use these df as per required. Here is the code of what I have done.

```py
    import pandas as pd
        commanFilePath = '\Projects\Pandas\Csv_Files\\'
        fileNametoImport = ['Employee.txt','Role.txt']
        listofdf =[]
        # load file to data frame
        for filename in fileNametoImport:
            fN,ext = filename.split('.')
            fN = 'df'+fN
            listofdf.append(fN)
            filewithpathname = commanFilePath + filename
            fN = pd.read_csv(filewithpathname,delimiter=',')
        print(fN)
        print(listofdf)
```

I want when I do `print(listofdf[0])` I should get my first dataframe which would be dfEmployee.

Comment: What are the output of the 2 `print`? Note also, your `commanFilePath = '\Projects\Pandas\Csv_Files\\'` was not correct (I've edited it. the character `\'` is a special char meaning `'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want listofdf[0] to be the first dataframe i.e., a dataframe for Employee.txt, then listofdf[0] should be `pd.read_csv('\path\to\Employee.txt', delimiter=',')`. The name `dfEmployee` doesn't really matter. So you need to append the output of `pd.read_csv` to listofdf.

```
import pandas as pd
commanFilePath = '\Projects\Pandas\Csv_Files\\'
fileNametoImport = ['Employee.txt','Role.txt']
listofdf =[]
# load file to data frame
for filename in fileNametoImport:
    fN,ext = filename.split('.')
    fN = 'df'+fN # <--- is this needed?
    listofdf.append(fN) # <--- remove this
    filewithpathname = commanFilePath + filename
    fN = pd.read_csv(filewithpathname,delimiter=',') # <---- this is the dataframe
    listofdf.append(fN) # <--- append this

print(listofdf) #<-- should contain two dataframes now
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like:

```
from os.path import join
import pandas as pd
folder_path = "\Projects\Pandas\Csv_Files"
file_names = ["Employee.txt", "Role.txt"]

dfs = [
    pd.read_csv(join(folder_path, file_name), delimiter=",") for file_name in file_names
]
```